# Razor code to compute CSS color on 3 color scale

Tags: css, razor

I'm translating an Excel sheet into a MVC Razor Engine web application. All is good except that some of the cells have conditional formatting based on a 3 color scale. -50 = red, 0 = yellow, +50 = green.  How can I select a css background color based on an integer input value?

Comment: How about having a CSS class to represent each color state and conditionally applying the class in the view?

Comment: Question wasn't clear.  Excel "three color conditional formatting" is a sliding scale, at least in this case. The colors change hue for each value between -50 to 50.  I was hoping to avoid setting up 100 classes.  But I might set up 9 ... three of each should be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SASS Variables for colors values:
https://davidwalsh.name/sass-color-variables-dont-suck

```
$brand-color: red;
$brand-new-color: rgba($color-brand, 0.8);
```